# Sending a JSON to a server

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

So I have this code creating a game in p5.js and I was planning on sending it to a server or something so that people playing it can save data. I have tried using saveJSON() within p5.js but that only downloads the relevant data which isn't very useful in this case. 
I then tried using JS cookies;

```
document.cookie = "systems =" + json.systems + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC";
```

but they all just end up [object,Object] so again useless. Wanted to know if anyone had any solutions that would allow the user to save the game either client side or server side that wont require them to upload a file?

Comment: If you're seeing `[object object]` or something similar, that just means you have to parse the object or reference a particular field. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: `saveJSON` write a file containing de JSON on your own disk.  So for saving info on the current game it's perfect.

Comment: Then using `loadJSON('file:///myfile.json')` you can retrieve that info.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a javascript object you can convert it to json via [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
JSON.stringify(json.systems)
```

Then to convert a json string to a javascript object:

```
JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

This doesn't seem like you need to save it on the server (although I could be wrong), checkout [web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Store the json in web storage

```
localStorage.setItem("jsonData", JSON.stringify(json.systems));
```

Then load it from storage

```
json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jsonData"));
```